# Insert a cell to "push" an output cell down so that my next output will not overwrite the last output

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, output

Normally when you evaluate a function, its result overwrites previous results. I would like to insert a cell between my function so and the last output (push down the last result} so that the new result does not overwrite the old result.

Comment: Simply write `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],""]`

Comment: Might this be an XY problem?

Comment: @xzczd - I will test it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the option inspector, and for the notebook (or whatever scope) you want this to work for, set OutputAutoOverwrite to False.

Comment: I would never have thought about this.  works great!